# Why does fetching from a DB cursor returns always the same result set with MyBatis and Spring Transaction

Tags: postgresql, cursor, mybatis, spring-transactions

My setup is Postgres database which is connected via JDBC driver to a Tomcat server (which is responsible for connection pooling), which again serves this data source via JNDI to an Spring application.

In the java application I use MyBatis and MyBatis-Spring for querying the database.
Now I want to page through a table using a cursor as shown in this simple example http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-fetch.html.

Since a cursor needs to be run within a DB transaction I annotated the relevant method with `@transactional` annotation provided by the Spring DataSourceTransactionManager (see http://mybatis.github.io/spring/transactions.html)

This is where the crazy part starts. On runtime every `FETCH FORWARD 1000 FROM CURSOR` queried by MyBatis mapper does return one and the same result set. So it seems the cursor position gets rolled back on every call. So it will return the first 1000 rows of the table avery time.

Why do the following fetches do not return the next chunks of records?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that MyBatis uses a cache mechanism which isn't quite intelligent in my eyes https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html.

In fact MyBatis by default caches all queries executed during a session. Session means transaction or per connection. So on AutoCommit this is no problem. But not for use with a **cursor where the fetch statement does not change within a transaction**.

So once the first data from the DB has been fetched from the cursor the result was cached in memory and no following fetches were queried to the DB.

The solution is the following line in the mybatis-config.xml

```
<setting name="localCacheScope" value="STATEMENT"/>
```

So the local session will be used just for statement execution, no data will be shared between two different calls to the same SqlSession.

For me it seems like a bug since the default caching scope makes no sense for DB cursors.